# Settting VCL controls properties from TThread.DoTerminate

Tags: multithreading, delphi, delphi-10-seattle

I'm using the  `TThread.DoTerminate` method to notify to the main thread which the *TThread* has terminated.  but as soon try to change the properties of some controls (buttons) from inside of the DoTerminate both controls just disappear of the form.

Also when I close the Form I'm getting this message

> Project ProjectTest.exe raised exception class EOSError with message
>   'System Error.  Code: 1400. Invalid window handle'.

This is a sample application to reproduce the issue.

```
type
  TFooThread = class;

  TFormSample = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Button2: TButton;
    Button3: TButton;
    ProgressBar1: TProgressBar;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
  private
    FooThread : TFooThread;
    procedure ThreadIsDone;
  public
  end;

  TFooThread = class(TThread)
  private
    FForm : TFormSample;
  protected
    procedure DoTerminate; override;
  public
    procedure Execute; override;
    constructor Create(AForm : TFormSample); reintroduce;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

var
  FormSample: TFormSample;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

{ TFooThread }

constructor TFooThread.Create(AForm: TFormSample);
begin
  inherited Create(False);
  FreeOnTerminate := False;
  FForm := AForm;
end;

destructor TFooThread.Destroy;
begin
  inherited;
end;

procedure TFooThread.DoTerminate;
begin
  FForm.ThreadIsDone;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TFooThread.Execute;
var
  i : Integer;
begin
  for i := 1 to 100 do
  begin
    Synchronize(
     procedure
     begin
       FForm.ProgressBar1.Position := i;
     end
    );
    Sleep(50);
  end;

  Terminate();
end;

{ TFormSample }

procedure TFormSample.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FooThread := TFooThread.Create(Self);
  TButton(Sender).Enabled := false;
end;

procedure TFormSample.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FooThread := nil;
  Button3.Visible := False;
end;

procedure TFormSample.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if (FooThread<>nil) then
  begin
    if not FooThread.Terminated then
     FooThread.WaitFor;
    FooThread.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TFormSample.ThreadIsDone;
begin
  //this code is executed but the controls are not updated
  //both buttons just disappear from the form !!!!
  //Also if I remove these lines, no error is raised. 
  Button2.Visible := False;
  Button3.Visible := True;
end;

end.
```

The question is : How I can  update the properties of some VCL control as soon the *TThread* is finished?

Comment: You say "if I remove these lines, no error is raised". Does that mean an error ***is raised*** if you don't?

Comment: Yes an error is raised (System Error. Code: 1400. Invalid window handle) when I run the thread, I wait for finalize and then  close the application .

Comment: Sorry missed that bit.

Comment: `DoTerminate` is executing in the thread context. All it does is calling `Synchronize` to fire the `OnTerminate` event. This explains why your code fails badly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<strike>It should be fine to update controls inside `DoTerminate` (as you are).</strike>
`DoTerminate` runs in the context of the thread. Therefore it is *not safe* to update controls from that method. The base implementation synchronises a call to the `OnTerminate` event.

So `OnTerminate` is already synchronised. And it will be safe to update controls from an `OnTerminate` event handler.

However, I would be more inclined to ***not*** have code inside the thread class calling the form because this creates a circular dependency. Rather have the form assign a handler for the `OnTerminate`event. This way code that controls the form will be in the form class. You can do the same with the control updates to indicate thread progress.

```
FooThread := TFooThread.Create(...);
             //WARNING: If you need to do **any**
             //initialisation after creating a
             //thread, it's better to create it
             //in a Suspended state.
FooThread.OnTerminate := ThreadIsDone;
//Of course you'll have to change the signature of ThreadIsDone accordingly.
FooThread.OnProgress := ThreadProgress;
//You'd have to define a suitable callback event on the thread.

//Finally, if the thread started in a suspended state, resume it.
FooThread.Start;
```

Avoiding circular dependencies is a little more work, but greatly simplifies an application.

> David mentions that you *can* create your thread in a running state. To do so safely you must:
>
> - Pass all necessary initialisation information into the constructor.
> - And inside the constructor perform **all** initialisation **before** calling the inherited constructor.

---

Also you have a mistake in your `Execute` method:

```
procedure TFooThread.Execute;
var
  i : Integer;
begin
  ...

  Terminate(); //This is pointless.
               //All it does is set Terminated := True;
end;
```

The thread terminates when it exits. All the call to Terminate does is set an internal flag to indicate the thread *should* terminate. You'd normally write your Execute method as follows:

```
begin
  while not Terminated do
  begin
    ...
  end;
end;
```

Then your form might have a button which calls: `FooThread.Terminate();`

This will cause your while loop to exit at the end of the current iteration. This allows the thread to exit "gracefully".

Comment: Thanks very much , using the `OnTerminate` event and starting the TThread suspended fixes the bug.

Comment: A few problems with this answer. `DoTerminate` executes on thread. Can do VCL stuff there. `Resume` is deprecated, use `Start`. No need to suspend if you initialise in the constructor.

Comment: *Errata*: I meant to say "Can't do VCL work there". In other words, first sentence of answer is categorically wrong.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thanks for the corrections. I have updated accordingly.